# regular expression to detect opening/closing pair characters in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, regex, markdown, nsregularexpression

I am writing a program to detect markdown emphasis syntax in text. For example, the bold syntax enclosed with `**`, and the italic syntax enclosed with `*`.

I have the following regex pattern:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex;
regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\\*{1,2}).+?(\\*{1,2})"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators
                                                                         error:NULL];
```

However, this pattern also detects mis-paired ones. For example, matching `* this is a **sample** text` will return `* this is a **` instead of `**sample**`.

How to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a back reference, with this pattern:

```
(\*{1,2}).+?\1
```

This means that whatever is captured in the first group (a single or double asterisk) it must be repeated later as `\1`.

For example:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex;
regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(\\*{1,2}).+?\\1"
    options:NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators
    error:NULL];
```